# Arch linux - режим гибернации

Tags: linux, загрузка, archlinux

Я новичок в linux, но все же решился поставить Arch. Хочу включить себе режим гибернации, но не понимаю, как это сделать. Читал доки, но все равно ничего не понял. Подскажите по братски, как включить режим гибернации?

Comment: про гибернацию и то как её готовить подробно написанно в АрчWiki - [Hibernation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation). `Я новичок в linux, но все же решился поставить Arch.` - тогда вам всё же стоит начать если не с Убунты то хотя бы с Manjaro которые юзерфрендли для новичков.

Comment: Да, я уже был на manjaro и fedora пробовал, но мне не понравилось рабочее окружение и особенно wayland

Comment: Также консольные команды через pacman работают гораздо быстрее

Comment: `pacman` и в `manjaro` есть, да и с выбором графического окружения там не должно вызывать больших проблем (kde, xfce, gnome, i3/sway, budgie, cinnamon, mate) из которых большинство можно запустить под иксами.

Comment: Да, это конечно хорошо, но я хочу сделать режим гибернации на arch. Я еще раз перечитал документ и немного не понятно вот что:
Это: mkinitcpio -P (нужно чтобы пересобрать образ initramfs?)
Зачем нужен resume_offset? За что он отвечает?
И последнее:  Как узнать  UUID swap раздела (я предполагаю, что нужно использовать sudo blkid, чтобы узнать UUID диска, на котором находится swap раздел)

Comment: `Это: mkinitcpio -P (нужно чтобы пересобрать образ initramfs?)` - да; `Зачем нужен resume_offset?` - наверное нужно для правильной начальной инициализации свопа при загрузки ядра; `За что он отвечает?` - на скока я понял это физическое смещение **начала** файла(своп-файла) на диске; `Как узнать UUID swap раздела` - запустите команду `lsblk -o +FSTYPE,UUID` и увидите какой UUID у каждого раздела в том числе и у своп-раздела.

Comment: Спасибо Большое:)